# How To Store Values In Non-Contiguous Memory Locations With SSE Intrinsics?

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, sse2

I'm very new to SSE and have optimized a section of code using intrinsics. I'm pleased with the operation itself, but I'm looking for a better way to write the result. The results end up in three `_m128i` variables.

What I'm trying to do is store specific bytes from the result values to non-contiguous memory locations. I'm currently doing this:

```
__m128i values0,values1,values2;

/*Do stuff and store the results in values0, values1, and values2*/

y[0]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values0,0);
cb[2]=cb[3] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values0,2);
y[3]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values0,4);
cr[4]=cr[5] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values0,6);

cb[0]=cb[1] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values1,0);
y[1]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values1,2);
cr[2]=cr[3] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values1,4);
y[4]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values1,6);

cr[0]=cr[1] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values2,0);
y[2]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values2,2);
cb[4]=cb[5] = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values2,4);
y[5]        = (BYTE)_mm_extract_epi16(values2,6);
```

Where `y`, `cb`, and `cr` are byte (`unsigned char`) arrays. This seems wrong to me for reasons I can't define. Does anyone have any suggestions for a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're look for one of the _mm_packXxx intrinsics.

Comment: I looked at those, but none of them seemed to do what I want. I'll go check again, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically can't -- SSE doesn't have a scatter store, and it's sort of all designed around the idea of doing vectorized work on contiguous data streams. Really, most of the work involved in making something SIMD *is* rearranging your data so that it is contiguous and vectorizable.  So the best thing to do is rearrange your data structures so that you can write to them 16 bytes at a time. Don't forget that you can reorder the components inside your SIMD vector before you commit them to memory.

Failing that, the `PEXTRW` op (_mm_extract_epi16 intrinsic) is pretty much the only way to pull a short from an SSE register and store into an integer register. The other approach available to you is to use the unpack and shuffle ops (`_mm_shuffle_ps` etc) to rotate data into the low word of the register and then `MOVSS`/`_mm_store_ss()` to store that low word to memory one at a time.

You will probably find that using a union, or moving data between the SSE and general purpose registers, will provide very poor performance due to a subtle CPU implementation detail called a [load](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2008/07/08/load-hit-stores-and-the-__restrict-keyword/)-[hit](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3687/sponsored_feature_common_.php)-[store](http://alex-simon.blogspot.com/2010/04/load-hit-store.html) stall. Basically, there's no direct way to move data between the register types; the processor has to first write the SSE data to memory, and then read it back again into the GPR. In many cases, this means it has to stall the load operation and wait until the store clears before any further instructions can be run.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When you say I can reorder the components in the SIMD vector are you referring to the unpack and shuffle ops?

Comment: And don't forget you can use masked moves/shuffles as well. For example, if you had an SSE register a=<`ABCD`> that you wanted to write onto memory line `XYZW` such that only the first and third words were overwritten (yielding `AYCW` in memory), then you could load the destination line into register b=`XYZW`, combine them with a masked-move to c=(ABCD & 1010) | (XYZW & 0101)=AYCW, and then save c back to memory.

Comment: scatter operations are introduced in AVX-512 (Xeon Phi) but this code does not need scatter operations because the indices where to store the values are known at compile time. And now (as opposed to the time of writing of the question) we know that the scatter operations (e.g. `_mm512_i32scatter_epi32`) in AVX-512 are for storing 32 or 64 bit integers only.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about SSE specifically, but generally the whole point of vectorised units is that they can operate very fast provided the data obeys particular alignment and formatting.  So it's up to you to provide and extract the data in the correct format and alignment.

Answer (score 2):

SSE does not have the scatter/gather functionality that you need, although this is probably coming in future SIMD architectures.

As has already been suggested, you can use a union, e.g.:

```
typedef union
{
    __m128i v;
    uint8_t a8[16];
    uint16_t a16[8];
    uint32_t a32[4];
} U128;
```

Ideally this kind of manipulation only happens outside any critical loops, as it's very inefficient compared to straightforward SIMD operations on contiguous data elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use union's to extract the bytes.

```
union
{
    float value;
    unsigned char ch[8];
};
```

and then assign the bytes as needed
Play around with union-idea, maybe replace the unsigned char ch[8] with a anonymous struct?
Maybe you can get some more ideas from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/sseintro.aspx)

Comment: I don't know about that; the simplest effective solution gets my vote every time

Comment: Except in this case it induces a huge load-hit-store stall.

Comment: @Crashworks: good answer/explanation above (+1) I may have misunderstood the original question (looked like he wanted the values in app-local memory-buffers)